# Link all li or img Tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, hyperlink, tags, parent

Hey I have a galleryscript wich generate a ul list with thumbnails. Now i want to give all this thumbnails the same link. 
Thats the Thumbnaillist:

```
<ul id="thumb-list" style="width: 2397px; left: 0px;">
    <li class="thumb0"><img src="img/th/0.jpg"></li>
    <li class="thumb1"><img src="img/th/1.jpg"></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

and I want it to be:

```
<ul id="thumb-list" style="width: 2397px; left: 0px;">
    <li class="thumb0"><a href="#gallerytop"><img src="img/th/0.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="thumb1"><a href="#gallerytop"><img src="img/th/1.jpg"></a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

This anker link "#gallerytop" should scroll the parentdocument. The Galley with the thumbnailslist is included as IFrame. Can somebody help?

I tried js replace...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
(function($) {
var site = $("#thumb-list");
site.html(site.html()
.replace(/<img /g, '<img href="#gallerytop"')
); 
return; })(jQuery) </script>
```

or via wrap

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
var a = $("<a>").attr("href", "#gallerytop");
$("img").wrap(a);
</script>
```

nothing helped :/

the Thumbnails are in a Iframe how i cann scroll to the anker link #gallerytop in the parent-document (main Frame)... sry for bad english

Comment: We can't help you fix your code if you don't post what you tried.

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` to find all the `img` tags, then a loop that uses `insertBefore` to add the `a` tags.

Comment: the Thumbnails are in a Iframe how i cann scroll to the anker link #gallerytop in the parent-document (main Frame)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/JayKandari/bX2PH/2/

use jquery's `wrap()` method to wrap objects around.

```
$("#thumb-list").each(function(){
 $(this).find("img").wrap("<a href='#gallerytop'></a>");   
});
```

Comment: thx my code...
parent-document:  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.ScrollToTop = function(){ 
  $('html,body', window.document).animate({
    'scrollTop':   $('#page1').offset().top
}, 1000);
};  </script>

Iframe:   <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){ 
    $("#thumb-list li").each(function(){
     $(this).find("img").wrap("<a onclick='window.parent.ScrollToTop();' target='_parent' href='#page1'></a>");   
    });   
});

 </script>

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, you can try this:

```
$('#thumb-list img').each(function(){
  $(this).wrap('<a href="#gallerytop" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('li').children().wrap('<a href=""></a>');
```